# Remove sorting of one specific column in ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I am working on an enterprise level ag-Grid which has globally set `enableSorting: true` for all columns. However, I have one column which must not use sorting and I want to switch it off for this specific column. When trying to configure each column, `AgGridColumnDefinition` type does not have `sorting` option, as it is mistakenly claimed in the ag-Grid reference. Info on this matter is generally scarce and obsolete.

Is there an ag-Grid guru who could help me with this?

Comment: Will look in a sec but off the top of my head I'm very sure you can use the same property or very close name on ColDefs. So in your ColDef you would just do something like `{ headerName: 'header', field: 'field', enableSorting: false }` and that should override the gridOptions.

Comment: It's actually suppressSorting on the column - will update with answer...

Answer (score 1):

Just checked one of my projects and it's suppressSorting on the ColDef. That's in the docs I'm pretty sure or what I just did was look at the type definitions I have since I use ag-grid with TypeScript. Here are the definitions where ColDef is for reference so next time you don't know an interface for a TypeScript project, know that they often ship with definitions or are available in DefinitelyTyped.

The version I happen to be using
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/a1f1fa8c028b61ebac605016d6ccda2d121d5239/dist/lib/entities/colDef.d.ts

Comment: Your help is much appreciated, sir. I will try this out on Monday and will let you know how it went. Thank you and happy Halloween 

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I get an error: "suppressSorting: boolean;' is not assignable to type 'AgGridColumnDefinition'".

Comment: The type is ColDef on the GridOptions. I just searched google for ""AgGridColumnDefinition" and literally this post is the only result that comes up, also searched all the ag-grid type definitions and nothing. Is that your own custom type or something? If you share your code and more of your environment, I'll help.

Comment: Thanks, it really seems the type is custom. I added ```suppressSorting: boolean``` to the type and edited the custom colDef accordingly, but it does not help :/

Comment: No way to help unless you share more - no idea why you're using a custom type, where you're doing assignment, initializing gridOptions, etc. - It's a really simple thing though. GridOptions have ColDefs, that have a property suppressSorting. If you can't figure it out from that, then I'd say you may need to learn more about the stack you're using.